# MacOS brew install libsndfile but still not found

Tags: c, macos

I just switched from windows to mac, and I was trying to use brew to install libsndfile for one of my C projects. But after installing it still shows cannot find it error in the terminal, and I seems not be able to figure out why.

`brew install libsndfile`
libsndfile 1.0.31 is already installed and up-to-date.

`gcc -lm -lsndfile -o skeleton skeleton.c`
fatal error: 'sndfile.h' file not found

Answer (score 8):

This is likely because, since M1, Homebrew [installs by default to /opt/homebrew](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/) and you will need to instruct it explicitly where to find the include and library files.

Try:

```
export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
```

..and then recompile. Add the above lines to your shell `.zprofile` (or `.profile`) to persist the settings for future use.

Comment: I love you. This worked for me!

Comment: Thank you, that put me on the right path! For some reason, brew did not put libsndfile.h into either of the locations you suggested, but I found it at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libsndfile/1.1.0/include`. I ended up copying it to /usr/local/include, because I could not get clang to find it otherwise, and that seems to have worked. Probably not how one is supposed to handle this though.